Hard/Interesting analytical problem to solve: $0 = a_{1} \ln(1+a_{2}e^{a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}})+a_{6}x^{2}+a_{7}x+a_{8}$
Is there some trick or approach I'm missing in attempting to solve \ref{1}, or better \ref{2}, analytically.
$$0 = a_{1}\ln(1+a_{2}e^{a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}})+a_{6}x^{2}+a_{7}x+a_{8} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$0 = a_{1}\ln(1+a_{2}e^{a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}})+ a_{6}\ln(1+a_{7}e^{a_{8}x^{2}+a_{9}x+a_{10}})+a_{11}x^{2}+a_{12}x+a_{13} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
The only approach I can think of for \ref{1} is by doing series expansions of $\ln$ and $e$ and then solving the polynomial, though with the nested nature of the exponential in the logarithm I can only take the first 2 terms of the taylor series to keep the polynomial order $\leq 4$ for any chance at a general analytical solution:
$$e^{a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}} \approx 1 + (a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}) + \frac{(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5})^{2}}{2!} + \mathcal{O}(x^3) \tag{3}\label{3}$$
$$ \ln(1+u) \approx u - \frac{u^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)\tag{4}\label{4}$$
$$ \ln(1+a_{2}e^{a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}}) \approx a_{2} + a_{2}(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}) - \frac{(a_{2} + a_{2}(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}))^2}{2}\tag{5}\label{5}$$
Then by subtitution of \ref{5} into \ref{1} it should still be solvable. The issue is that the taylor series to the second order for $\ln(1+x)$ and first order for $e^x$ are not accurate enough for what I'm attempting to do with these equations. So the specific question for a better solution approach comes to mind, or on the other hand some general rule of this not being analytically solvable would also be helpfull so I don't spend more time on it.
The only guarantee about the coefficients that may be helpful is that they come from a physical system where a positive solution will always exist, given that the logarithm and exponential are used or approximated with sufficient accuracy.
Numerical Solution
Some of these coefficients are made up of 50-100 sine and cosine terms so there is a reasonably high computational cost to numeric solutions, however currently with some sampling to determine a reasonable search interval and Brent's Method I can get the correct solution in ~20 iterations.

Edit 1
Multiple powerseries that converge to the values of the roots in term of the coefficients would also be a great help, though I am even less sure how I would go about finding one for my problem.
If we remove the first and second order polynomial terms form equation \ref{1} I can find an expression for the roots, but I don't think this approach can be extended to \ref{1} so its maybe of limited help:
$$0 = a_{1}\ln(1+a_{2}e^{(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5})})+a_{6} \tag{6}\label{6}$$
$$-\frac{a_{6}}{a_{1}} = ln(1+a_{2}e^{(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5})}) \tag{7}\label{7}$$
$$e^{(-\frac{a_{6}}{a_{1}})} -1 = a_{2}e^{(a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5})} \tag{8}\label{8}$$
$$\ln(\frac{e^{(-\frac{a_{6}}{a_{1}})} -1}{a_{2}}) = (a_{3}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{5}) \tag{9}\label{9}$$
From there the roots can be found with the quadratic formula:
$$K = \ln(\frac{e^{(-\frac{a_{6}}{a_{1}})} -1}{a_{2}}) \tag{10}\label{10}$$
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-a_4 \pm \sqrt{a_4^2 - 4a_{3}(a_{5}-K)}}{2a_{3}} \tag{11}\label{11}$$

By “analytical”, do you mean something like a series solution?

A powerseries of the roots in terms of the coefficients would also help like a series expansion of polynomial roots, or am I missunderstanding what you mean by series solution? If you just mean a series expansion of \ref{1} I'm not sure how that helps me in finding the roots
